# Certian iframed Website refuses to connect

Tags: javascript

If I try to iFrame some sites, such as lets say https://google.com, it says that google.com refuses to connect.

Can anyone give a script of some sort that can bypass this? Thanks

Comment: No you can get a script to bypass it. It is a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the settings google has on their servers, they do not allow other websites to display google inside of an iframe. They have done this by adding `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin` to the headers in the response. There is no way to get around it, this is enforced for security reasons, more specifically as the mdn web docs for [X-Frame-Options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) states it's enforced to prevent [click-jacking](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Types_of_attacks#click-jacking) attacks